# Multiple Choice question about an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with real or complex entries, and such that $A^3=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with real or complex entries and such that $A^3=0.$ Which of the following options holds?
>   1. $(I+A)^3=0$.
>   2. $I+A$ is invertible.
>   3. $I+A$ is not invertible.
>   4. Necessarily $A=0$.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DonAntonio's suggestion,we see that  $(I+A)(I-A+A^2)=I+A^3=I$ ,since $A^3=0.$ This gives $|(I+A)(I-A+A^2)|=1 \implies |(I+A)||(I-A+A^2)|=1 \implies |(I+A)| \neq 0.$ So option 2 seems correct.

Comment: I think you're supposed to determine whether each holds in turn. It's possible more than one does or that none do.

Comment: option $(2)$ holds $\implies (3)$ does not hold. The option $(4)$ is trivial. But I am not sure about option $1$. Can you help?

Comment: Take $A$ to be the zero matrix.

Comment: Thanks.Then option $(1)$ is clearly false.

Comment: Indeed. $ $ $ $

Comment: That a (square) matrix $C$ is "invertible" means that there is some matrix $D$ such that $CD=I$. This has nothing to do with determinants.

Comment: Well @Andres, it turns out it does: a matrix over a commutative ring is invertible iff its determinant is a unit in that ring. True, one does not *have* to resort to determinants to check this, but once one learns about it that becomes a pretty nice and easy way to check invertibility.

Comment: @DonAntonio Using determinants here reveals a misunderstanding: If you have an inverse, you know the matrix is invertible, period. If you have an inverse, you do not use it to conclude that the determinant is nonzero, so that you can conclude that the matrix is invertible, meaning that it has an inverse. Anyway, my apologies if you feel remarking this is unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: No @AndresCaicedo, I think *both* your comments, put together, are quite enlightening and you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$(I-A)(I+A+A^2)=I-A^3\ldots$$

Think it slowly. Well chewed this hint solves all first three questions. The fourth one is almost trivial.